# Resonance of lone pair of nitrogen in 4‐nitroaniline and piperidin‐2‐one

Tags: organic-chemistry, resonance

While working out some questions on comparing the basic nature of various compounds, I came across the following two compounds:

[image: A: 4‐nitroaniline; B: piperidin‐2‐one]

In case of **A** I could see several resonating structures, and also the −*M* effect of the nitro group. So justifying based on the number of resonance structures, I could tell that the lone pairs are more delocalized in **A** than in **B**. Hence **B** is more basic.

**However, on verifying my answer I found that A was more basic.**

The only reason I could come up with is that in compound **A**, majority of the resonance includes a negative charge on carbon, but in compound **B**, the negative charge lands on the more electronegative oxygen, which better succeeds in stabilizing it.
But it doesn't seem right for me.

Can anyone please tell me the correct reason for this?

Comment: I dont know why 2 people downvoted this. Is there any problem with the question?

Comment: -1. It's unclear what you're trying to ask. Do you want to find out which compound is more stable? *quality vs quantity* is like *apples vs oranges* - you can't compare them.

Comment: But then on what aspects do we compare these compounds?

Comment: @aniruddhaDeb yes I have edited the question to make it more clear now

Comment: You might ask if the hydrochloride salts of these two compounds exist.

Comment: well that could be one way. But I want to know how the resonance of lone pair could be used to determine basicity here

Comment: One of these compounds has a basic amine nitrogen. The other is a non-basic amide.

Comment: Yes but by resonance how can it be explained?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Considering that you're referring to the difference in the number of resonating structures, you're right in that aspect. 4‐Nitroaniline does have more resonating structures than piperidin‐2‐one. But in organic chemistry, you should be knowing that for a phenomenon to happen, there have to be several contributing factors.

While this includes the number of resonating structures as *one*, you have to take into consideration the other factors as well. And this includes the other factor you have mentioned in your answer — the position of the negative charge.

Since carbon is an atom which has an electronegativity of 2.55 (According to the Pauling scale), a negative charge on it would make it highly unstable, *lowering* the *resonance energy*, thus *reducing* the resonance stabilization in it. Nitrogen and oxygen have electronegativity of 3.04 and 3.44, respectively, thus a negative charge on those atoms would *increase* the resonance energy, thus *increasing* the resonance stabilization.

Comment: @Firefox1921 Thank you for the answer, however isn't the negative charge going to oxygen in BOTH the cases? That is why i do not think it should be the main reason

Comment: Yes @VAMSIKRISHNACHILAKAMARRI, the negative charge is going to the *oxygen* in both cases. But it **isn't** going on *carbon* in both the cases, right?